# How to refresh the first tab on action bar spinner item selected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, recyclerview-layout

I am trying to refresh the 1st tab on spinner item selected but it showing the error No view found exception showing when I am trying to call the same fragment.

Refresh Same Fragment Code:

```
DashBoardFragment currentFragment = new DashBoardFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    //fragTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
    //fragTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
    fragTransaction.replace(R.id.home_container, currentFragment);
    fragTransaction.commit();

 12-30 10:58:34.222 11811-11811/com.cashpundit.cashpundit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.cashpundit.cashpundit, PID: 11811
                                                                       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0071 (com.cashpundit.cashpundit:id/home_container) for fragment DashBoardFragment{c2b9283 #2 id=0x7f0c0071}
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1098)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:532)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: what exception add error logcat.

Comment: added logcat in question

Comment: what is there in DashBoardFragment layout file ? have you attached any file in setcontentview()?

Comment: I am not attached setcontentview().

Comment: due to that this error comes

Comment: share more activity code

Comment: I am going to refresh the Fragment. In activity i am added se contentview()

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Refresh() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
    for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
        if (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible()) {
            if (fragment instanceof SummaryReportsFragment) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragTransaction.detach(fragment);
                fragTransaction.attach(fragment);
                fragTransaction.commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```